# Lego Mindstorms programming - which book do you recommend for kids?

Tags: lego-mindstorms

There's a ton of books on Lego Mindstorms programming out there - not least from the always-excellent [No Starch Press](http://nostarch.com/catalog/lego).

Which book would you recommend for direct use by, or for teaching, children - primarily the 9-13 age range, but possibly a bit younger and a bit older too.

I'm assuming that NXT 2.0 is the language to learn.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a good question for here, since "best" will be more of a discussion. Anyway, "Lego Mindstorms NXT The Mayan Adventure", by James Floyd Kelly is good because it has five puzzles that must be solved by building different robots, and students learn more from each.

Comment: "Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect." If you don't agree with the _topic_ of the question, the correct response is to flag it, not to downvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest letting your children learn the language that is issued with the robotics kit at first. They will learn all the basics required (such as decision making, looping, reading data and outputting data and so on...). There is a book available on programming in NXT-G.

Once the feel comfortable with the language and are starting to feel limited in what they want to do I suggest they move onto something a little more challenging such as text based programming.

I would refer them at first to NXC (which is procedural programming). John C Hansen has written to books on programming with NXC.

Once they "mastered" NXC, I would suggest they have a look at leJOS, which is programming the NXT in java. They can learn all about object orientated programming and the benefits it provides. There is also a book on programming Minstorms in java.

I hope this helps. (This is not a have-to-do way to learn how to program the NXT, but I found it very comforting. :) ).

PS: Remember, to learn something there are more resources than books, eg online tutorials and so on.